# set string in TextEdit which allows only int

Tags: c#, textbox, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress.
In my project i have control (textEdit), which EditValue is binded to the property of "int" type.
Problem is that control allow to enter only numbers.

My task is: while form is in edit mode, the textEdit should display word "Automatic", and only after safe button press there should be generated number.
Now in edit mode textbox shows "0", is it possible to make it show "Automatic" in case of "0".

there is the property, to which the textBox is binded:

```
int fEventNr;
public int EventNr {
    get { return fEventNr; }
    set { SetPropertyValue<int>("EventNr", ref fEventNr, value); }
}
```

everything works except that it shows "0" and I don't know how to make him show "automatic"
maybe someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to your problem:

```
textEdit1.Properties.CustomDisplayText += new Properties_CustomDisplayText;


void Properties_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (yourCondition)
        e.DisplayText = "Automatic";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtEdit.Properties.NullText = "Automatic";
txtEdit.EditValue = null;
```

Consider changing `public int EventNr` to `public int? EventNr` so that you can be sure that the user HAS NOT supplied any value if the EditValue is null and you should generate it "Automatic"aly :)
I believe it's a bad practice to consider 0 as [value not set]. That is the reason why they invented the null.

Answer (score 0):

On the properties panel go to Properties -> `Mask . Set "MaskType" to RegEx` and set `"EditMask"` to `\d*`. If you don't want integers to begin with zero(s) then set `"EditMask"` to `[1-9]+\d*` instead.
Alternatively you can do it by code :

```
this.textEditIntegersOnly.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "[1-9]+\\d*";
this.textEditIntegersOnly.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.RegEx;
```